# Arduino Ethernet + PHP Request

Tags: php, mysql, arduino, ethernet

I'm writing code for Arduino + ethernet shield to send data with the `$_GET` method (PHP), to a Mysql database.

I've tested the PHP code on the browser and it worked fine, but on Arduino it didn't work. I can not tell where the problem is. I've been looking in other forums and can not find any answer. Below is my code, I would appreciate it if anyone could help resolve the crash

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 1, 60 }; //IP (WEB CLIENT)
byte server[] = { 192, 168, 1, 8 }; //IP (SERVER) 
EthernetClient client;

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  if (client.connect(server, 8095)) {        
    Serial.println("CONECTED");
    client.print("GET http://192.168.1.8:8095/prs/Query.php?a=");
    client.print(2);
    client.print(" HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    Serial.println("Information sent successfully!"); 
    delay(1000);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Conection fail");
  }
}

void loop() { 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. unfortunately your question is quite unclear and kind of "here is my code, correct it for me!" which is not welcome here.

Comment: Sorry if I was misunderstood, but I'm just asking someone more experienced in this area to help me find the problem with my code because I've tried everything and I can not get it to work.

Comment: What output do you get in the serial monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.print("GET http://192.168.1.8:8095/prs/Query.php?a=");
client.print(2);
client.print(" HTTP/1.1\r\n");
```

This isn't a well-formed HTTP 1.1 request:

1. It contains a protocol, hostname, and port in the request line. This is not appropriate outside of HTTP proxy requests.
2. It does not contain a `Host` header.
3. It does not contain two newlines after the request.

A proper request might resemble:

```
"GET /prs/Query.php?a=2\r\nHost: 192.168.1.8\r\n\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice the Ethernet client variable/object is called cliente (with an e on the end) where its declared, but below this the name of the object is client (no e on the end), if you correct this difference in name does it work?

```
EthernetClient cliente;

client.connect(server, 8095)
```